# Why does the following code behave so strangely? Python3.5 vs Python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-lawyer

As the title says, why does the following code behave so strangely?

```py
a = {
    0: 0
}
b = []

for i in a:
    del a[i]
    a[i + 1] = 0
    b.append(i)

print(b)
```

In Python3.6 it prints `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, whereas in Python3.5 it prints `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. Why?

Comment: Structurally modifying a dict while iterating over it is completely unsupported. Knowledge of the internal details of how it plays out is only useful for debugging; a correct Python program will never trigger this behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 Granted, it’s unsupported. I’m curious as to why that loop isn’t infinite.

Comment: "If you mutate something while you're iterating over it, you're living in a state of sin and deserve whatever happens to you."

Comment: 'Knowledge of the internal details of how it plays out is only useful for debugging'... and satisfying curiosity.

Comment: @user2357112 is there some reference that you could point to, for that declaration of non-support. I mean, on python.org, not on SO. I couldn't find any via google.

Comment: Oh well, I found this "Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may raise a RuntimeError or fail to iterate over all entries" at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both cases the loop is not infinite for a simple reason: you create an iterator over the dict. This is simply an object that internally knows the size of the hashtable and keeps track of the index at which it arrived. When looping over this iterable it will simply check each slot in the hashtable to see if it is filled, and if it is filled it yields it otherwise it continues to increase the index.

Your dictionary never grows in size, it always has zero or one element so no reallocation of the hashtable is done and the iterator continues to the end of the hashtable.

Furthermore: small integer hash to themselves:

```
>>> print(*map(hash, range(10)))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

This means that when you insert `i+1 == 1` it is going to end up in slot `1` of the hashtable, and the iterator will find it in the next loop. Same happens with `2` etc. Until the hashcode is big enough to be "wrapped" over to the beginning of the hashtable. The iterator index does not wrap over, since it knows the size of the hashtable.

Python3.5 and python3.6 probably have different initial hashtable sizes (keep in mind that in python3.6 the `dict` class was reimplemented to be ordered).

---

Obviously **all** of this is an implementation detail. There is no language guarantee that the iterator acts like this, it's just a side-effect of the implementation. A future implementation might detect any change to the `dict` and raise an error instead of continuing.

Comment: So a hash table in 3.6 is sized for 5 keys even if dict is created with 1?

Comment: @SuperShoot Most mutable collections will start with some "spare room" to avoid reallocating at the first insert.

Comment: That makes sense. Cheers.

Comment: I thought `for i in a` is dealing with an iterator over the **valid keys of `a`**. At least that's what I thought the semantics was. In which case, this should have looped infinitely. Any other behavior to me counts as a flaw in the interpreter. And of course, I would be perfectly ok with it if the interpreter proactively prevents me from mutating a dictionary while iterating over it.

Comment: On second thoughts, maybe the reasonable behavior would have been if the loop iterated just once. I say so because, during the very 1st itn, though we are mutating the dict, we aren't changing the number of valid keys (earlier, `0` was the only valid key, and after the first iteration, `1` would be the only valid key.) Since the num of valid keys remains unchanged during the iterations, the iterator has no reason to go on indefinitely yielding values. So, I suppose this loop should have executed **just once**. IMHO that would have been a reasonable behavior than what has been reported by OP.

Comment: @fountainhead Yes, but it requires keeping track of an extra counter... and for what? Modifying the dictionary during iteration is "undefined" so it does not make sense to "optimize for that case". So the only reason you'd want to do that is to optimize iteration (since you could skip iterating over the last empty slots), but you'd probably find that it almost never gives any real benefit but now you have to increment/decrement an extra counter + comparing it for every access. It's not sensible to slowdown all code to make the result of a wrong piece of code "less wrong".

Comment: @Bakuriu Let's say the dict had 3 valid keys (`0`,`1`, and `2`). And suppose we don't mutate the dict. Then the loop would have iterated exactly thrice. Whatever counters or other internal machinery was employed to provide that behavior should, IMHO, also suffice to ensure that the loop executes just once in the OP's use case too. Mutation or no mutation, the iterator should always look at NumValidKeys, rather than NumSlots, to decide that it's time to stop.